# Fuse-box (VueJS + Font-Awesome + Bootstrap) - not watching scss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, vue.js, font-awesome, fusebox

I'm trying to create a demo project with :

- Fuse-Box
- VueJS
- Font-Awesome
- Bootstrap (css/js/icons)
- Jquery

I forked on GitHub [fuse-box-seed](https://github.com/shenron/fuse-box-vue-seed)

**My problems:**

When I'm running dev `node fuse`, I have to save several times my .scss files to display the new version in my browser.

When I build the project `node fuse dist` the `./dist/ressources` folder is empty. I expect to have my fonts (Font-Awesome, bootstrap)

I have no error, just missing font files ...

Thank you very much for  your help !

Answer (score 0):

When you bundle bootstrap with FuseBox make sure it's bundled through javascript, not via import in sass.

```
import "boostrap/dist/bootstrap.css"
```

The thing is when you bundle it using SASS imports (or any other CSS pre-preprocessor) the actual root folder is lost, the structure if flattened, and FuseBox fails to resolve the paths.

Comment: In fact I use the import of scss because I have to rewrite some variables. And I guess if I import css it's not possible.